# Android Build mm command is failing on ubuntu

Tags: android

I am facing this error when executing the mm command to build android module.

sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unterminated `s' command
make: *** ]2;pcz-2T124:: No such file or directory.  Stop.

Please share the fix for this.

Thanks
Raja

Comment: r u build in ur source project?

Comment: yes, I did source build/envsetup.sh, then moved into a module which has it's own Android.mk and then executed mm command.

Comment: yes I did lunch command also. I have started using make from the source tree root to build my module. make <mod> from T worked but mm is still not working.

Comment: can u post ur screenshot if any?